# getting attribute of a custom object does not work as expected

Tags: python

I am learning to use `__getattr__` to treat custom object as if they were dictionaries alike.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, breed, size, color):
        self.breed = breed
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ret = getattr(self, name)
        return ret

dog = Dog('corgi', 'small', 'brown')
print(dog.get('breed'))
```

it gives the error of RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. As I went through debugging, I found that inside the function getattr, the 'name' value is 'get', not 'breed'...why is that?

Comment: `__getattr__` does **not** make a custom object like a dictionary (that would be the Mapping ABC - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping). When you attempt to access dog.get, which doesn't exist, you call `__getattr__`, which uses `getattr`, which calls `__getattr__`, which uses `getattr`, which...

Comment: "I am learning to use `__getattr__` to treat custom object as if they were dictionaries alike." You are confused, that is *absolutely not what `__getattr__` is for*

Comment: `__getitem__` is the method that backs the use of `[...]` for indexing. `get` is a method provided by mapping types to be similar, returning a default value rather than raising a `KeyError` for undefined keys. If you want your class to have a `get` method, just define a `get` method.

Comment: If you use `dog.foo` and there is no attribute `foo`, then `dog.__getattr__('foo')` will be called if defined rather than raising an `AttributeError` right away.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your explanation. It makes sense! I tired and it worked out. I was reading someone's code and there is this line that goes like dog.get(something) where dog is a custom object that has just one function called __getattr__,  which is why I thought get() would be just a shorthand way of writing __getattr__(). I still don't know why he wrote it that way, but I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Yes, it does make sense! Your elaboration and chepner's explanation have me understand why it get stuck in a recursion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want it to behave like a `dict`, you'd probably want to override `__getitem__` making sure you do your appropriate checks. (It's also used to make it like an array as well.)

Then you can do `dog['breed']` -- if you want `get` to work you can define a `get` function to do the work you're looking for. `__getattr__` requires a lot of caution, since even trying to invoke a method will go through `__getattr__`.

Comment: So it doesn't just check attributes, but also methods of an object. Noted! Thank you!

Comment: Strictly speaking, objects don't have methods. A "method" is a `function`-valued *class* attribute, and because `function` implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), accessing those attributes via an instance *creates* a callable `method` object.